# Socket.py has no attribute AF_INET

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to create a simple HTTP Client and I'm having trouble creating a simple socket. I use PyCharm and it highlights the AF_INET attribute of socket.py as non-existent and my script also crashes at runtime when it tries to get the AF_INET property. I checked my imports and I'm sure I have them right. Thanks!

```
import re
import socket

def getAddress():
    address = input('Please enter a http address and a port (example: http://httpbin.org):\n')
    parseAddress(address)

def parseAddress(address):
    urlMatch = re.compile(r'^(.*:)//([A-Za-z0-9\-\.]+)(:[0-9]+)?(.*)$')
    searchResult = urlMatch.match(address)

    host = searchResult.group(2)
    port = '80'
    portTest = searchResult.group(3)

    if portTest is not None:
        port = portTest.replace(':', '')

    connectToServer(host, port)

def connectToServer(host, port):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    #s.bind((host, port))
    #s.send('HTTP REQUEST')
    #response = s.recv()
    #print(response)
```

I also checked for any files named socket.py and there aren't any in my project structure. Also when I ctrl+click the socket import it points me to the right file in the Python install folder :(

Comment: Add ```print socket.__file__``` to your code to make sure you are importing correct module. (Your IDE might be wrong when resolving imports)

Comment: Works for me.  Do you have a file called `socket.py`?  Maybe you're importing the wrong thing.  Also, which version of Python are you using?

Comment: Printing outputs this: C:\Users\Václav Parchomenko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socket.py and my Python version is 3.7.0